# Laravel custom middleware, 'too many redirects'

Tags: laravel, middleware

tengo un **middleware** personalizado que comprueba si el campo de los usuarios `active` es **true** (1) o **false** (0).

Mi middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class checkUserActive
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!$request->user()->isActive()){
            return redirect()->route('error.user-not-active');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Lo tengo registrado en `kernel.php` :

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'check_user_active' => checkUserActive::class,
        ...
     ];
```

Y lo estoy llamando de la siguiente manera en `web.php`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','check_user_active']], function () {...

....

    //Vista usuarios no activos
    Route::get('/error/user-not-active','ErrorController@userNotActive')->name('error.user-not-active');
....
});
```

El resultado que obtengo en el explorador es :

```
Esta página no funciona. La página localhost te ha redirigido demasiadas veces.
Borrar las cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Comment: Si tienes una ruta para usuarios no activos protegida por el middleware de usuarios activos, cada vez que intentes cargar esa ruta no va a parar de redirigirte porque cada vez que te redirige vuelve a comprobar si el usuario está activo... y como no lo está, redirige a la ruta de usuarios no activos que está protegida por el middleware de usuarios activos, y como no está activo redirige a la ruta de usuarios no activos que está protegida por el middleware de usuarios activos, y como no está activo... etc. En resumen: quita el middleware de esa ruta o no va a poder acceder un usuario no activo!

Comment: Cierto !, es verdad voy a poner la ruta afuera, que sea accesible siempre para poder redirigir. Gracias !!